# custom data validation in angular 4

Tags: forms, angular, validation, typescript

i'm using my angular 4 app as a frontend application using  web services . 
i have a component that showing form user details . so to validate my form i have a one cretaria   is all full inputs (user information) that was imported from the web services is required .
for exemple if have username and telephone inputs showing in my updatecomponent and the username are 'xxxxxxx' and telephone is empty , if i try to clean the username input and submit the form , it should not submitted because the username was not empty from the backend and i have to mention like a warning to fill the username input for submit the form . and for the telephone input , there is no problem , because the input came empty from the start .
so what kind of validation form  may i  do ?

Comment: Angular forms will not update nor validate the form upon programmatic changes to the form's input. You can use `updateValueAndValidity` on the form after getting the data from your web service, if I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use form validation.
This article can helps you:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html